# Adding Two Lists of Different Types Into Another List

Tags: c#

I have:

```
List<BuyDataViewModel> BuyDataList = new List<BuyDataViewModel>();
List<RentDataViewModel> RentDataList = new List<RentDataViewModel>();
```

As you can see, both are of `BuyDataViewModel` or `RentDataViewModel` type (model) so I cannot simply use `AddRange` as below:

```
BuyDataList.AddRange(RentDataList); //Combined List
```

Is there a way in which I can have a larger list that contains both my `BuyDataList` and `RentDataList`, as well as retaining its respective model?

Comment: .NET version of that Java article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd799517(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @BenN LOL!  Whoops...  I've provided answers to too many java questions today, I didn't even see the C# tag :-P

Comment: Cheers guys! I'll take a look at the articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should have a common base class.

If you want to iterate over that list and handle each item respectively to its concrete type, then you will need to implement the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).